# "Has recommended answer" filter also includes questions with answers written by a Recognized Member

Tags: bug, answers, collectives, filtering

When I navigate to the R Language Collective [page](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language) and filter the questions by the "Has recommended answer" attribute, I see questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689055) which are clearly labeled "Answer recommended by R Language".

[image]

That's fine, but I also see questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75637383) which do not have that label. They *were* however answered by a Recognized Member of the collective.

[image]

Is that a bug? Or should I conclude that all answers by Recognized Members are "recommended"? (I hope not.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Collectives, there are two types of "Recommended" answers:

- **explicitly recommended**: A Recognized Member or Admin of the Collective has chosen to mark an existing answer (not authored by them) as the "recommended" answer for the Collective.  In this case, you will see a "Answer recommended by <Collective name>" label on the answer.
- **implicitly recommended**: If a Recognized Member or Admin of the Collective directly answers the question, that answer is considered to be recommended on the basis that it was provided by a member that could otherwise recommend answers.  In this case, you will see the Collective badge next to the answerer's user info. Note that the Collective badge will stay associated with the answer even if the user no longer is a Recognized Member/Admin in the future.  This only applies to answers provide while the user is a Recognized Member/Admin, and not to answers they provided before gaining that status.

A question can have only one explicitly recommended answer, but may have multiple implicitly recommended answers.  Also, having an implicitly recommended answer does not prevent marking any of the answers as explicitly recommended.

The idea is that an answer provided by a Recognized Member/Admin was effectively self-vetted by the Recognized Member/Admin, and therefore are equivalent to an explicitly recommended answer from the Collective's point of view.  In theory, the author reviewed any existing answers on the question and deemed them not worthy of being endorsed, so wrote their own.

---

*for context: I am a Tech Lead on one of the teams working on Collectives.*

Comment: This seems very odd to me. I expected Recommended Answers to be curated. If I look at the recommended answers in the R Collective right now, 100% seem to be written by RMs and "implicitly recommended". Some are high quality, many are routine responses to basic queries. From the perspective of someone trying to find the top quality answers, this is not a helpful filter at the moment.

Comment: Having forgotten all about this, I just checked the R Collective questions with a recommended answer. Three of the top ten are not even the highest scoring answers _for that question_. They are simply recommended because they are written by a Recognized Member. It's a shame as this could be a useful feature. I 
 would like to read curated answers to keep up with new libraries, discover neat tricks etc. Would it be possible to introduce a filter which allows users to distinguish between explicitly and implicitly recommended answers? I think I'm mostly interested in the former.

Comment: @SamR yes, we’ve talked quite a bit about doing just that. Unfortunately the team was hit hard by the last round of layoffs, and I’m currently on sabbatical, so for the summer, the remaining team is very limited in what they can achieve. Yes, we will probably do this, but not in the immediate future.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Can understand it might not be a priority in the circumstances. Looking forward to the team being in a better position in future.